# Meaning, Properties and Definition

Tags: philosophy-of-language

According to my understanding, language is an attempt to describe the properties of objects. A sentence can only succeed so far as to be able to list the properties or characteristics.

There are words which have only denotation and by themselves have no meaning. For example 'aeroplane'. It only serves the purpose of denoting a class of objects called aeroplanes. If I were to define 'aeroplane', do I have to list all properties?

But properties can be derived from other properties. Which properties are sufficient to constitute definition?

Is it *always* guaranteed that properties can be fully substituted for the denotation? Does anything lies beyond properties? That is, if sentences are descriptions, and they can only list properties, are there some 'inherent meanings' language (or properties) can never capture?

Comment: I wonder if you're asking about the 'problem of attributes'. We can describe properties but not that to which properties belong. Is that it? Properties are enough to define an object in order to distinguish it, but do not refer to that part of the object that is not a property. This is what led Kant to the 'thing in itself', But I'm unsure whether this is what you're asking about. . . ,

Comment: @PeterJ : I cannot conclude if this answers if listed properties can be fully substituted for denotation? It makes sense to settle if properties are able to distinguish; that is the aim of research. But the 'thing in itself' -is this just a mental construct or has any sort of denotational reality? All that exists are just properties?

Comment: See [Theories of Meaning](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meaning/).

Comment: "If I were to define 'aeroplane', do I have to list all properties?" We cannot obviously define everything.

Comment: In math and logic (and maybe science) we have to use defined term without ambiguities. This is not possible (and maybe not necessary) in natural language.

Comment: See [Language game (philosophy) and Wittgenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_game_(philosophy)) : it is reasonable to assert that in many cases we learn how to use terms (and thus their "meaning") without definitions at all.

Comment: See also [Philosophy of language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_language) : language has many "uses"; the main one is to communicate. One one of its use is "to describe the world". See [Functions of language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakobson%27s_functions_of_language) and [Speech Acts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/speech-acts/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is it always possible to effectively (without any loss of knowledge) substitute denotation with the exhaustive set of its properties? If we study a theory, is there anything more to it than its formulae and properties, something which can only be understood mentally, and in no way be communicated to a learner?

Comment: if a "meaning" cannot be communicated,,, what can be ? Not a meaning.

Comment: Can you give an example of the word that has meaning then? Aeroplane is meaningless and what is meaningful?

Comment: @rus9384 So is meaning equivalent to exhaustive set of properties? For a formal theory, is there not a meta meaning associated with it? Something which can define it in one go?

Comment: @rus9384 If we talk about Turning Machine, is there an overall meaning, which can define its structure and the consequences of its structure, which are its properties? Something all at once.

Comment: Humans do not operate in formal languages. But no TM can define itself, if you ask that. But for each TM there is another TM that contains all the information about the first TM. And I can't say that meaning is tied to properties. Then properties are themselves comprehended by some meanings. So, what are the meanings of properties? People see similarities between various objects and give names to these similarities.

Comment: @Ajax - I can't respond fully here, but your comment to me above raises all the right questions. Your question leads naturally into the the 'problem of attributes', which is what led Kant to the thing-in-itself as a logical necessity. The alternative, as you say, is that all that exists are properties. A solution for this problem requires exploring beyond the fundamental dualism of Kant and his tradition.

Comment: @PeterJ Properties, in my (revised) opinion, are just categorisations to manage information. Redness, circularity and so on... are perceptions (we now know there is no such thing as red -just optics and our eye). No two natural things have identical property. Redness varies, and so do other properties. It is, therefore, unreasonable to assume independent existence of properties. We can only state that every object is unique; and it seems to me, _because_ a thing exists, therefore it is a logical necessity for it to be just a thing-in-itself.

Answer (score 1):

> According to my understanding language is an attempt to describe the properties of objects

Language is primarily, fundamentally and essentially an I & thou relation and not an I & it relation. That language does describe the properties of objects occurs as a by product of this essential purpose of language and not primarily so.

It seems from your question you are more concerned with understanding how it is that language distinguishes objects rather than characterises them; for example, an aeroplane from a lamppost. One need not define or characterise an aeroplane or a lamp-post to do this. One needs only a single property to distinguish between the two.

Were you distinguishing a larger class of objects then you would require many more distinguishing properties, and generally it's simpler to group together properties then.

> Is it *always* guaranteed that one can always substitute properties for denotations?

No.

Comment: _If one cannot always substitute properties for denotations_, then what? What is the implication of this fact?

Answer (score 1):

I think if I may say so that you are a tad narrow in your characterisation of language.

## Properties and language

Language must be used to refer to *objects* if it is to describe the *properties of objects*, so at least that extension is required. And since there can be no description of objects without reference to those objects, I should have thought that if anything it is the reference to objects that is logically prior in our characterisation of language.

'A sentence can only succeed so far as to be able to list the properties or characteristics.' 'The' properties ? *All* the properties or only those relevant to the point or purpose of the sentence ?

Among properties do you count negative properties as real or genuine ?

Do you allow emergent properties ? Disjunctive properties ?

> (1) Are properties universals or tropes? (2) Are properties attributes of particulars,
> or are particulars just bundles of properties? (3) Are properties categorical (qualitative) in
> nature, or are they powers? (4) If a property attaches to a particular, is this predication
> contingent, or is it necessary? (David M. Armstrong, 'Four Disputes about Properties', Synthese, Vol. 144, No. 3, Dispositions and Laws of Nature (Apr., 2005), pp. 309-320: 309.)

## Properties and definition

In a definition, X = Y, the properties included in Y can be (a) only necessary, (b) only sufficient (as in Wittgenstein's family resemblance concepts), or (c) necessary and sufficient, to press the matter no further. Any of these, (a) - (c), may be sufficient to constitute definition?

## Language and communication

Aside from this tangle of issues about properties, I'd stress the communicative function of language:

> We can use [language] to
> convey wishes and commands, to tell truths and to tell lies, to influence our
> hearers and to vent our emotions, and to formulate ideas which could probably never arise if we had no language in which to embody them. We can
> even use language to communicate with ourselves; in fact, such self
> communication seems to constitute much of what we call "thinking." (William G. Moulton, 'The Nature of Language', Daedalus, Vol. 102, No. 3, Language as a Human Problem (Summer, 1973), pp. 17-35: 17.)

Not all of these functions involve, so far as I can see, the description of properties of objects; and all of them, I venture, at least do far more than this as part of their essential purpose.